# Google VR GvrReticlePointer not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I'm making a VR Menu for my app in unity (5.4), using Google VR (1.30)

So there's the camera in the middle of the scene (MainCamera with "MainCamera" tag and GvrReticlePointer prefab as child)
And then i have another object GvrViewerMain prefab.

In the EventSystem object I have the usual EventSystem script, GvrPointerInputModule (active) and StandaloneInputModule (for the screen UI when I use it, deactivated for the moment).

So when i create the objects to interact to, they activate their scripts to handle the pointer events (these objects are Canvas with a RawImage and a Text as children).

So when I move the pointer over any of these I don't get any interaction... any of you know what should I do?

The script for pointer events is right bc when I use the STD ModuleInput and hover with the mouse they work

It's just like the GvrReticlePointer is not working or not sending the right events

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding GvrPointerPhysicsRaycaster.cs to Player game object.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what was the actual problem but downgrading to GoogleVR 1.10 solved the problem